# How can I find the age of a person from a query based on a given date?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

How can I find the age of a person from a query on a given date from the date of birth.

I want to run a query that will return the age of everyone in a table, on any date of the following year calculated from their date of birth.

I want to return the age in years they will be, say on the 01/09(September) of the next year.

Todays date is 02/09/2015

If the date of birth is 09/10/2006 the answer is 9

If the date of birth is 28/01/2006 the answer is 10

Any ideas?? Anyone?

Comment: Look at `DateDiff` [Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php) Should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_in_table) gives you the difference in seconds. Now just convert to years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Expression in the Control source of a textbox on a form
Current Date: 01/01/2015

```
Table1:
|Birth_Date |
|01/01/1995 | = 20
|01/01/1994 | = 21
```

Expression:
    =DateDiff("yyyy",[BirthDate],Date())

The age will update every time you open the form

or

VBA(will need a button)

```
Sub Bottun1_Click()

Me.MyTextBox = DateDiff("yyyy", Me.BirthDate, Date)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

DateDiff only returns the difference in calendar years.

For a true age as of today, use a function like this:

```
Public Function AgeSimple( _
  ByVal datDateOfBirth As Date) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years from datDateOfBirth to current date.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
' After an idea of Markus G. Fischer.
'
' 2007-06-26. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim datToday  As Date
  Dim intAge    As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  datToday = Date
  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDateOfBirth, datToday)
  If intYears > 0 Then
    ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
    ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of datDateOfBirth.
    intAge = intYears - Abs(DateDiff("d", datToday, DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDateOfBirth)) > 0)
  End If

  AgeSimple = intAge

End Function
```

For any combo of dates, use this function:

```
Public Function Years( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of year counts.
' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased step wise one year from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2000-11-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' 2000-12-16. Leap year correction modified to be symmetrical.
'             Calculation of intDaysDiff simplified.
'             Renamed from YearsDiff() to Years().
' 2000-12-18. Introduced cbytMonthDaysMax.
' 2007-06-22. Version 2. Complete rewrite.
'             Check for month end of February performed with DateAdd()
'             after idea of Markus G. Fischer.

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDate1, datDate2)
  ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
  ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a full 12 months period
  ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", -intYears, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      ' Offset negative count of years to continuous sequence if requested.
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  ' Return count of years as count of full 12 months periods.
  Years = intYears - intDiff

End Function
```